# Index DataFrame with (Multi)Index containing only some of the DataFrame's levels

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I wish to take a dataframe with a multiindex and index it with another (multi)index containing a strict subset of the dataframe's levels. Levels in the dataframe not in the other (multi)index should have all rows returned. An example:

```
>>> df
              col
num chr
1   a    0.845402
    b    0.099432
    c    0.507409
2   a    0.684363
    b    0.582436
    c    0.666528

>>> df['col'].unstack('chr').mean()
chr
a    0.764883
b    0.340934
c    0.586968
dtype: float64

>>> df['col'].unstack('chr').mean().nsmallest(2)
chr
b    0.340934
c    0.586968
dtype: float64

>>> df['col'].unstack('chr').mean().nsmallest(2).index
Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='chr')
```

Now, I would like to return all rows of `df` containing `'b'` or `'c'` in the `'chr'` level, and any value in the `'num'` level. Additionally, I would like to attempt the same thing, where the index returned in the last step is a `MultiIndex` (i.e., when `df`'s index has more than two levels):

```
>>> df
                  col
num chr foo
1   a   bar  0.790995
        baz  0.883363
    b   bar  0.240376
        baz  0.309544
    c   bar  0.637943
        baz  0.265628
2   a   bar  0.783172
        baz  0.612230
    b   bar  0.729979
        baz  0.846814
    c   bar  0.809676
        baz  0.821503

>>> df['col'].unstack(['chr', 'foo']).mean()
chr  foo
a    bar    0.787084
     baz    0.747796
b    bar    0.485177
     baz    0.578179
c    bar    0.723809
     baz    0.543565
dtype: float64

>>> df['col'].unstack(['chr', 'foo']).mean().nsmallest(2)
chr  foo
b    bar    0.485177
c    baz    0.543565
dtype: float64

>>> df['col'].unstack(['chr', 'foo']).mean().nsmallest(2).index
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['bar', 'baz']],
           labels=[[1, 2], [0, 1]],
           names=['chr', 'foo'])
```

I would like to select all rows of `df` whose index contains `('b', 'bar')` or `('c', 'baz')` in the last two levels and any value in the `'num'` level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest solution may be to retrieve the desired rows individually and `pd.concat` them. For the `Index` solution:

```
idx = df['col'].unstack(['chr', 'foo']).mean().nsmallest(2).index
selected = pd.concat([df.xs(label, level=idx.name, drop_level=False) 
                      for label in idx],
                     axis=0)
```

When `idx` is a `MultiIndex`, use `level=idx.names` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I can only do it with `get_level_values` and `isin`

```
s=df['col'].mean(level=[1,2]).nsmallest(2).index.tolist()

df[pd.Series(list(zip(df.index.get_level_values(1),df.index.get_level_values(2)))).isin(s).values]
Out[163]:
                  col
num chr foo
1   b   bar  0.240376
    c   baz  0.265628
2   b   bar  0.729979
    c   baz  0.821503
```

Comment: Yikes... hopefully there’s a more idiomatic solution

Comment: @BallpointBen why not reset_index()? multiple index still under developing , so it can have more potential issues